# call servlet method name display(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) from another servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am developing a shopping cart using servlets, have two servlets :
1. ShopingCart.java
2. TotalAmount.java

In ShopingCart.java i have created sessions and synchronise them using

```
synchronized(session)  // lock session protect this from multiple threads
      {
       TotalAmount cart = (TotalAmount)session.getAttribute("Cart");

       if(cart == null)  // new sesssion, just create a cart
       {
        cart = new TotalAmount();
        session.setAttribute("Cart", cart);
       }
      // I have to call cart.display();
```

and my display method in TotalAmount.java contains (request,response) as parameters.
so, how can i pass the request and response to display method?

yes, i need request and response parameters in display method to save some variable data in session in TotalAmount.java

Please Help..

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) is what you need to be looking at, especially the `forward` method.

Comment: yes, actually i know about RequestDispatcher forward method, but how we let the control know about Display method must be called in TotalAmount servlet?

I think in RequestDispatcher we let the control know that, TotalAmount.java servlet should be called, any perticular method ?? is not it??

Comment: Do you want to forward the request to another servlet, or do you just want to call some method in some class while passing the request and response? If you want to forward the request, you have to implement your logic in the servlet's `service` method.

Comment: I want to forward request to another servlet's Display(request,response) method..
what should i do for the same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can pass the request and response to display method of TotalAmount.java by calling

```
Display(request,response);
```

As I already have the object of TotalAmount in ShopingCart.java

Answer (score 0):

As per Java EE specification, servlet are independents and the only official way to interact with one is via their `service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)` or `doXXX` method.

If you want to call a specific method of another servlet you have 2 broad solutions :

- make the objects know each other by dependancy injection (Java EE CDI, Spring framework, etc.) - clean and neat provided you have one DI mechanism
- manually register them via static method - say you want to access Servlet2 from Servlet1

  ```
  class Servlet1 implement HttpServlet {
      private static Servlet2 servlet2 = null;

      public static void setServlet2(Servlet2 servlet2) {
          this.servlet2 = servlet2;
      }
      // ... other code
          servlet2.display(...);
      // ...
  }
  class Servlet2 implements HttpServlet {
      @Override
      public void init(ServletConfig config) {
          Servlet1.setServlet2(this);
          // ... other init code eventually
      }
      // ...
   }
  ```

  It should work but is not very *nice* because of the static misuse.
- forward to the other servlet and pass a request attribute to indicate that a special action is requested (assuming Servlet2 is named "Servlet2" in web.xml)

  - in Servlet1 :

    ```
    request.setAttribute("DISPLAY", true);
    request.getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("Servlet2").forward(req, resp);
    ```
  - in Servlet2 :

    ```
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
        if (req.getAttribute("DISPLAY") != null) {
            display(req, resp);
        }
        else {
            super.service(req, resp); // or directly your code
        }
    }
    ```

  Still a nice solution because attribute will not be set in a direct call (of course, you can use `req.getRequestDispatcher("/Servlet2URL")` instead of `getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("Servlet2")`)

Comment: Hi, thanks Serge for replying with so much coded answer.. :)
but i solved my problem just by:

Display(request,response);